# acts-as-taggable-on context names plural or singular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Is it correct to assume that act-as-taggable-on context names must be plural? "skills" vs "skill"? The documentation is not explicit about the naming conventions.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :*skills*, :interests
end

@user = User.new(:name => "Bobby")
@user.tag_list = "awesome, slick, hefty"  
@user.skill_list = "joking, clowning, boxing" 

@user.tags # => [<Tag name:"awesome">,<Tag name:"slick">,<Tag name:"hefty">]
@user.skills # => [<Tag name:"joking">,<Tag name:"clowning">,<Tag name:"boxing">]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already figured this out by now, but yes you are correct. Context is plural.